# How can I use asp validation to validate the range of date input in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-validators

I am trying to validate my date input field with asp-validation, but  I keep getting this type of error [image: Error_Image]

This is what I did in my Model:

```
 public static readonly DateTime MinDate = new DateTime(2000, 01, 01);
        public static readonly DateTime MaxDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-4);

        [Display(Name = "Date of Birth:")]
        [Range(typeof(DateTime), nameof(MinDate), nameof(MaxDate), ErrorMessage = "Date must be between January 1, 2000 and 4 months from now.")]
```

I tried to simply type the date as strings to see if my code runs properly and it does.

```
[Range(typeof(DateTime), "01/01/2000", "02/06/2022", ErrorMessage = "Date must be between January 1, 2000 and 4 months from now.")]
```

I believe the way I am using the `DateTime` object is wrong, although I can't figure out what the issue is exactly.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're confused about. The [constructor you're using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute.-ctor?view=net-8.0#system-componentmodel-dataannotations-rangeattribute-ctor(system-type-system-string-system-string)) takes a Type, a String, and a String. The strings themselves need to be parseable into the Type specified.

Comment: In addition, do you not know that you can't use DateTimes as values in attributes because they are not compile-time constants?

Comment: Well he obviously doesn't know, otherwise wouldn't ask in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that attributes accept only constants as parameters. DateTime object can not be a constant. But you can create a custom attribute

```
    [Display(Name = "Date of Birth:")]
    [RangeDateAttribute( ErrorMessage = "Date must be between January 1, 2000 and 4 months from now.")]
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }

public class RangeDateAttribute : RangeAttribute
{
    public RangeDateAttribute()
      : base(typeof(DateTime),
              new DateTime(2000, 01, 01).ToShortDateString(),
               DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-4).ToShortDateString())
    { }
}
```